# Get argument as unicode string from argparse in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, unicode

Code from my [last project](https://github.com/Kraymer/flinck/blob/master/flinck/__init__.py#L43), that has to work on Python 2.7 and Python 3.
I want to get a path as a unicode string from `argparse`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Organize your movie collection using symbolic links')
parser.add_argument('media_src', metavar='FILE|DIR',
                    help='Media file or directory')
args = vars(parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:]))
try:
    args['media_src'] = unicode(args['media_src'], "utf-8",
                                errors="ignore")
except NameError:
    pass  # py3
```

Can that be done more elegantly without relying on duck typing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review. I hope you get great answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `unicode` for Python3 when you get a `NameError`.
You should make a small note that explains `unicode` is not defined in Python3, rather than having the user guess, what `#py3` means.

```
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    # Define `unicode` for Python3
    def unicode(s, *_):
        return s
```

You should use the [`type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22947181) parameter to `add_argument`, to change the type returned.
And so if you don't want to have `unicode` in the global scope in your Python3 environment you can bind it to that functions scope.

```
def build_to_unicode():
    try:
        unicode
    except NameError:
        def unicode(s, *_):
            return s

    def inner(s):
        return unicode(s, "utf-8")

    return inner

to_unicode = build_to_unicode()
```

Also your lack of a definitive style to pass variables to the parser made it harder for me to read your code.

```
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    # Define `unicode` for Python3
    def unicode(s, *_):
        return s

def to_unicode(s):
    return unicode(s, "utf-8")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Organize your movie collection using symbolic links')
parser.add_argument(
    'media_src',
    metavar='FILE|DIR',
    help='Media file or directory',
    type=to_unicode)

args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])
# If you really want to.
args = vars(args)
```